# How to check/get document expiry in Couchbase using .Net SDK?

Tags: api, couchbase

I need to get document expiry in Couchbase using .Net SDK.
Get API does not return the document expiry it is just returning value.

Comment: Same issue with the Java SDK :'(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to get the expiry right now. However you can use a view to do this task:

Create a [view](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Views/views-intro.html) that emits the expiry:

```
function (doc, meta) {
      emit(doc.id, meta.expiration);
}
```

Then you can [query](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.0/view-queries.html) the expiry for any key by doing:

```
var query = bucket.CreateQuery("design-doc-name", "view-name”, false).Key("key-name");

 var result = bucket.Query<dynamic>(query);
 foreach (var row in result.Rows)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(row);
 }
```

Please remember that a offset expiry is converted to an epoch timestamp cluster side.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and efforts. It resolved my issue.